# What would prevent a new AGM battery from fully charging?

Tags: charging, low-battery

What can prevent a new out-of-the-box AGM battery from fully charging, given that neither age nor sulphation are factors?

Specifically, one of the six cells in my brand new Parts Unlimited battery is only developing 1.1V potential. The battery was activated by the store, in front of me and had six equally filled bottles of sulfuric acid drained into them (specific gravity 1.32). I was told it would not be fully charged at activation but "should" be able to turn over my V-Twin motorcycle. It took me over 1/2 hour to bring the battery home and install it, and when I tested it out, it did not turn over the engine. I left it on a battery tender overnight and it still would not turn over. I jumped it with my truck for nearly 30 minutes and I was able to start my motorcycle one time, but the battery was down to 11.8V again within an hour.

For over a week I have been searching for some help on problems with new batteries but all searches seem to show tips on restoring dead batteries or proper activation practices.

The problem exists in one cell which is only developing 1.1V between the cathode and anode, so the plates are not likely short-circuited. This is strange to me, because lead-acid chemistry is normally pretty reliable. Visual inspection shows the cell to look exactly like the others, with plates and glass matting sandwiched inside. So I am trying to find what manufacturing defect or activation error could have caused this cell to only develop 1.1V.

Comment: My motorcycle battery had a complicated activation procedure that involved wait times after pouring and then more wait before charging - beyond that I have no suggestions other than to go back, battery and receipt in hand and claim warranty.

Comment: Some of the auto repair YouTubers frequently say "New doesn't mean Good".

Comment: Exactly... New doesn't mean "good".  Take it back.  You could try a "wake up".... AGM's can come back to life via a 3-5 cycle action.  You charge it, nearly fully discharge it, and charge again (5x).   SOmething like an automotive light bulb can make a pretty good load for the discharge part.   Don't over-discharge it (stop at 8V!!!!!)

Comment: As a further update I went on a dive and there are no easy to find resources for voltage vs specific gravity of the electrolyte when the voltage is so low. I'm throwing an upvote at this question because it asks for specific mechanisms that lead to low output voltage - though I suspect that it would get more mileage over at the chemistry stackexchange.

Comment: @Bryan only if I assume the problem is chemistry rather than mechanical. I can't make that assumption yet without any way to put a hydrometer into a dry cell. As to refund, well, it would be nice to first eliminate the possibility that I did something wrong. So I don't do it again.

Comment: @Kyle I wouldn't fully discharge a lead-acid battery that I cared about, least of all a starting battery. It's bad for them and shortens their life and capacity. Especially starting batteries.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Its how you wake up a lead acid battery.   Breaks sulfation off the plates.  If you don't take it down to 8V, you aren't doing a complete job of it.  This isn't something I'm pulling out of the air...  My company goes through about 200,000 lead acid batteries a year...  I've been paying attention to what the vendors tell us